# How to Run Multiple Dynamic Queries in a PostgreSQL Function

Tags: postgresql, function, dynamic-sql

I am having some issues figuring out how to run multiple dynamic queries in a single function.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cnms_fy22q2.test_function(
    fyq text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 -- logic
    TRUNCATE TABLE 'schema_' || fyq || '.my_table'
    DROP TABLE 'schema_' || fyq || '.my_table';
END;
$BODY$;
```

I am generally getting syntax errors, like `ERROR: syntax error at or near ...`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Apart from not actually using dynamic SQL, your first dynamic query is also missing the semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply concatenate strings to make a dynamic sql statement. Take a look at [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html) and [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-sql-execute-immediate.html).

In your case, you could use it like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cnms_fy22q2.test_function(
    fyq text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    -- logic
    EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE schema_' || fyq || '.my_table';
    EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE schema_' || fyq || '.my_table';
END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Both of these worked well but I am giving your's the check as it followed my original method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the format function which will return a string and execute in your function.

```
create function permanently_delete_table(fyq text) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    declare
    begin
         EXECUTE format('TRUNCATE TABLE schema_%s.my_table',fyq); 
         EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE schema_%s.my_table',fyq); 
    end
$$;
```

Demo in [sqldaddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/bfb709a5)

Comment: Better use `%I` instead of `%s` for proper escaping ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ddc359bd452959b17069fe06d309cdf5))

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a third option that I came up with which combines the queries inside a single `EXECUTE format();` statement, here's what I came up with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cnms_fy22q2.drop_summary_tables_function(
fyq text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  COST 100
  VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 -- logic
  EXECUTE format(
  'TRUNCATE TABLE schema_%s.my_table;
  DROP TABLE  schema_%s.my_table', fyq, fyq);
END;
$BODY$;
```